# Problem sending web API to Spotify using Laravel and Guzzle package

Tags: laravel, oauth, authorization, guzzle

I'm trying to communicate with Spotify using web API.
So here's the case. In order to retrieve any information from Spotify, first I need to be authorized by Spotify. To do so, I need to send a post request to `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token` containing authorization credentials(containing client_id and client_secret), and then in response, I should receive an access token which later I shall use to retrieve any other information.
Here's a quick Spotify documentation on how it works:

[image]

So the problem here is that I'm doing everything I should but I don't get the token in response.

Here's my code using the Guzzle package in laravel :

[image]

And instead of an access token as a response, This HTML output is what I'm receiving from Spotify in return (Without any further information of the problem and any error code):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are misinterpreting this line?

```
Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>
```

It looks like you are doing this:

```php
base64_encode($client_id) . ":" . base64_encode($client_secret)
```

But perhaps they want this:

```php
base64_encode($client_id . ":" . $client_secret);
```

That is, assuming you have base 64 encoded them at all as this is not actually shown in your code.

---

Additionally, the documentation states that it wants `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding.

**# Sending Form URL Encoded Requests**
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#sending-form-url-encoded-requests

To meet this requirement, it looks like you may need to add `asForm()` to the request.

```php
$response = Http::withHeaders(...)->asForm()->post(...);
```

Comment: That's a fair point. I've tried that but still I'm getting that error.

Comment: I have added to my answer. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: That was right! Sending body parameters asForm() was the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

thanks...below is the working code from above

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$client_id = 'YOUR CLIENT ID';
$client_secret = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET';

$post = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';

$clientKeys = base64_encode($client_id . ":" . $client_secret);

$response = Http::withHeaders([
  'Authorization' => 'Basic '.$clientKeys
 ])->asForm()->post($post,[
   'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
 ]);

 $response->json();
 $access_token = $response['access_token'];
```